# Jetpack Compose - Application crashes when clicking on the LazyColumn's item

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I recently started coding with Jetpack Compose but now I've ran into issue.

My goal is when clicking on the LazyColumn's item it will navigate and display information on the Detail's Screen.

The code worked well, when I was using normal object. But for my college assigment I needed to get data from Firebase and display it using the MVVM pattern.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun DetailsUI(navController: NavController, articleId: String?,viewModel: ArticleViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
 var expanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
 val articleResponse = viewModel.articleState.value

 Scaffold(
 ) {
  when (articleResponse) {
   is Loading -> ProgressBar()
   is Success ->Column(){
    var newArticle = articleResponse.data.filter { article -> //the problem area that logs indicated
     article.id==articleId
    }
       ArticleHeader(image =newArticle[0].image)
       ArticleTitle(title =newArticle[0].title , author = newArticle[0].author )
       ArticleContent(content =newArticle[0].title )

     }




   is Error -> Utils.printError(articleResponse.message)
  }
 }

  }
```

ViewModel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ArticleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCases: UseCases
):ViewModel() {
    private val _articleState = mutableStateOf<Response<List<Article>>>(Response.Loading)
    val articleState: State<Response<List<Article>>> = _articleState

    init {
        getArticles()
    }

    private fun getArticles() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            useCases.getArticle().collect { response ->
                _articleState.value = response
            }
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
2022-06-09 00:43:35.248 12215-12215/com.example.flow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.flow, PID: 12215
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.flow.DetailScreenKt$DetailsUI$2.invoke(DetailScreen.kt:99)
        at com.example.flow.DetailScreenKt$DetailsUI$2.invoke(DetailScreen.kt:92)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2158)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2404)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2585)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2547)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:620)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:786)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:105)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:456)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:425)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@dde2781, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@6665026, AndroidUiDispatcher@95fe467]
```

Perhaps, filtering the `articleResponse`isn't a best idea, but I didn't want to provide an additional method to retrieve a single article from Firebase, so filtering was an easier solution. Nevertheless, I would be happy to receive the solution that would allow my idea without getting my application crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a crash because the response does not include the article you're looking for, and your code assumes it is there.

Change this

```
var newArticle = articleResponse.data.filter {       
    article.id==articleId
}
```

to

```
val newArticle = articleResponse.data.firstOrNull {       
    article.id==articleId
}
if (newArticle != null) {
    // display article
} else {
    // display Article not found error
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This is indeed solved the crash problem. I guess I would need to search another method on to display information.

Comment: If you are clicking on a list of articles then the article must exist. I would suggest you look at the logic in your code to pass the ID.

Comment: yet again you were right, I changed parameter from id to title and it started displaying the article.  Look like when firestore date parcelize to my data class it leaves the id as null, when I actually hoped it would also add document's id to the object via `val article = snapshot.toObjects(Article::class.java)`. Nevertheless, thank you for your help!