# firstOrNull function is unresolved

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the `LazyVerticalGrid` I'm trying to click on the item and it would transfer me to the Detail Screen to provide more information of the specific object, and I followed this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552882/10533650)

Unfortunately in the DetailScreen the `firstOrNull` shows  as `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:`:

```
  when (plantResponse) {
            is Loading -> ProgressBar()
            is Success -> Column( modifier= Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                val newPlant = plantResponse.data.firstOrNull{ plant ->
                    plant.id == plantId
                }
```

Perhaps as the error indicates it is indeed unsuitable for the type of data I'm trying to pass. Perhaps there is an alternative function that would help me to display the data from from the object on the Detail Screen.

Here is also the Viewmodel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PlantViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCases: UseCases
): ViewModel() {
   
    var plantResponse by mutableStateOf<PlantResponse>(Response.Loading)
        private set

    var openDialogState = mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        getPlants()
        

    }
    private fun getPlants() = viewModelScope.launch {
        useCases.getPlants().collect { response ->
            plantResponse = response
        }
    }
```

As per request I have added Success class:

```
   sealed class Response<out T> {
    object Loading: Response<Nothing>()

    data class Success<out T>(
        val data: T
    ): Response<T>()

    data class Error(
        val e: Exception?
    ): Response<Nothing>()
}
```

Here is also the Plant Repository class:

```
typealias Plants = List<Plant>
typealias PlantResponse = Response<Plant>

interface PlantRepository {
    fun getPlantsFromFirestore(): Flow<PlantResponse>

   }
```

I would be grateful for any guidance.Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: We need to see the definition of your Success class to know what type `data` is. Preferably, show PlantResponse and all subclasses.

Comment: @Tenfour04 as you have requested I have added the Success class and my Repository class let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: The `data` of a `PlantResponse`, which is really a `Response<Plant>` is of type `Plant`. Does `Plant` implement `Iterable`? If not, then why would it have a `firstOrNull()` function? Btw, IMO you are using `typealias` in a way that makes code much harder to read and may be leading to you misinterpreting the types of your own code.

Comment: Hey, @Tenfour04 I appreciate that you took time to pinpoint where the issue lies, it supposed to be `Response<Plants>` instead of `Response<Plant>` and changing it helped to resolve the error. Thank you for your guidance.